# Hibernate Unknown Entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two jar files with hibernate classes mapped. One jar file is perfectly working and for the next jar file it is not mapped. I get Unknown Entity exception. Persistence.xml is good but i dont know why this is happening. Any guess what mite be the issue???

Comment: A stack trace would be helpful, this question gives very little info.

Comment: sorry i missed it, thanks manyxcxi

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com.test.Equipment       at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:223)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke

Comment: you can edit your question to add this stack trace and delete the comment... it would look better.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have [`@Entity`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/persistence/Entity.html) on your `Equipment` class.

This annotation (`@Entity`) is marking a class as Hibernate (JPA) entity.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a refactoring issue.  I refactored my entity package but forgot to change the component scan path to the new package name.  After that was realized and changed, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following Annotation on top of your Entity Class Equipment. Change the table name accordingly if required :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Equipment")
@XmlRootElement
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package Test;

import java.util.EnumSet;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport;
import org.hibernate.tool.schema.TargetType;
import org.junit.Test;

import Entity.Users;

public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] arg){
         try {
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new MetadataSources( serviceRegistry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction=session.beginTransaction();
        Users users=new Users();
        users.setId(2);
        session.save(users);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        sessionFactory.close();
         }catch(Throwable th){
                System.err.println("Init SessionFactory creation failed" );
                System.err.println(th);
                throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(th);
         }finally {

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: it is better to add a small description about your code